# Is there a faster way to connect edges (f key) around a closed loop of eges quickly?

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

I'm trying to fill in the edges along the circle across its two sides, but with so many of them it's going to take very long selecting them individually, is there a faster way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Select the 2 circles and press W > Bridge Edge Loops

Comment: @moonboots Oh thanks man! That worked perfectly :)